# Connection failed: Access denied for user

Tags: mysql

I am trying to access database on remote server with normal user (testuser) with no GRANT privileges. When I try to access the database using the above user I get the following error:

> Access denied for user 'testuser'@'%' to database 'test_db'

I do not have any database interface to directly grant privileges to this user. I have SSH root access to the server. How do I grant privileges to this user?

Answer (score 0):

Login to mysql command line interface with your root user. Run the below commands to give access

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'testuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: Tried but no luck.

Comment: Your password may be incorrect. When you are logging in with testuser you may be entering incorrect password